# VBA - Username of open workbook (read only)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

If an open workbook (located on a server) is in read only mode, how can I display the active username using VBA?

I've looked into `.WriteReservedBy` but this only shows the name of the person that last saved the file with a password.

Comment: This looked intriguiing and a quick search for *VBA network owner* produced [File owner attributes through Excel VBA](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.programming/saSZ1ylixr4) which seems to work well. I'm just posting a link as any answer would seem to plagiarize on some level.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/845084/how-to-get-excel-to-show-username-of-person-that-has-file-open

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be a comment but my reputation is too low

I've seen this but never needed the info...

Things to try:

- ThisWorkbook.UserStatus - array with all current users for the file open as exclusive or shared
- Environ("USERNAME")
- CreateObject("WScript.NetWork").UserName
- API calls:

.

```
Declare Function WNetGetUser Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetUserA"
( _
    ByVal lpName As String, _
    ByVal lpUserName As String, _
    lpnLength As Long
) As Long

Declare Function GetUserName& Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" _ 
(ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long)
```

.

more details about these APIs:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/161394
- http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=768

---

- WMI [Win32_NetworkConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394220(v=vs.85).aspx):

---

```
Public Function GetActiveUser(Optional ByVal computer As String = ".") As String
    Dim wmi As Object, itm As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & computer & "\Root\CIMv2")
    itm = wmi.ExecQuery("Select UserName from Win32_NetworkConnection", , 48)
    GetNetActiveUser = itm
End Function
```